# Herstein mapping problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is not a homework problem, just one I am having difficulty seeing.  I pulled out my copy of Herstein's Abstract Algebra to brush up on some algebra and came across one of his harder problems on mappings...now I'm wracking my brain trying to solve it and am coming up with a deadend.

Let $S$ be the set of all integers of the form $2^m 3^n$, $m \ge 0$, $n \ge 0$, and let $T$ be the set of all positive integers.  Show that there is a bijection between $S$ and $T$.

It doesn't give any other restrictions on $m, n$, so I'm assuming they don't have to be integer.

Comment: If there exists such a bijection then $S=T$ (since $S\subset T$) & so $7$ must be expressed as $2^m3^n!$

Comment: Assuming $m,n\in\mathbb R$ seems quite unreasonable to me, given a) the naming, b) the fact that all other sets are integers and c) $\mathbb N\subset \{2^r|r\in\mathbb R^{\geq 0}\}$.

Comment: @SugataAdhya No, there must be only a bijective map between $S$ and $T$, for which the sets only need to have the same cardinality (which they have).

Comment: @ElmarZander: where did I go wrong in my logic?

Comment: @SugataAdhya There's no need that $7=2^m3^n$ for any $n,m$. Whether you assume $m,n\in\mathbb R$ or $m,n\in\mathbb N$ makes no difference. You just need some bijection $\phi:S\to T$ and $\phi(2^m3^n)=7$ for exactly one pair $(n,m)$.

Comment: So we have to show that there exists a bijection.  That is, the mapping is both injective and surjective.  So what would that mapping be then?  I'm trying to keep it in the context of the basics because this is literally chapter 1.3 of his book.  It's listed under the harder problems, but even if we don't actually define the mapping, and we just need to show the mapping is both injective and surjective, we should be able to find one, right?

Comment: Here's my rationale on how this problem works... The set S is the set of all x such that x=2^m*3^n for nonnegative integers m and n.  as long as 2^m*3^n is unique to all values of m and n, the set S can be made into a bijection by some mapping f such that f:S -> T.  Is that it?  It would certainly seem that the set is then ordered by < and each natural number i in T corresponds to the ith member of the set S.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst: You have made me chalenge by this problem. I think it needs more work either. What we have is the function $f$ from $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ by $(m,n)\to 2^m3^n$ is an injection but not a surjection. We need another well defined function and I am thinking about it.

Comment: We still need the function that sends every x in S to a natural number in T for all natural numbers in T.  our function f: S -> T would be a compsosite function, like if      g: (Z^nonneg x Z^nonneg) -> N by g(m,n) = 2^m*3^n and then f: S -> T where f(g(m,n)) = y in N.  We need to show that then f is a bijection... i was originally looking for the function but @Ben below did something instead.  He sent T to S...seems like it works as well too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't think $m,n$ have to be integers, then $S = T$, because you can set $m=0$, and letting $n$ increase continuously from $0$ to infinity, you will hit every positive integer.

If $m,n$ are forced to be integers, use Schröder-Bernstein.

Edit: If you don't know Schröder-Bernstein, then do you know that $T \times T$ is in bijection with $T$? You can use that fact.

Edit 2: Maybe here is an easier way to see it (when $m,n$ are nonnegative integers). Define a function $f:T \to S$ as follows: there clearly is a smallest element of $S$, let $f(1)$ be that number. Then there is a smallest element of $S\setminus \{f(1)\}$, let $f(2)$ be that number. Continue recursively. This defines an injection $T \to S$, and it must in fact be surjective because for any $x \in S$, $f(x) \ge x$, so there must be a $y \le x$ with $f(y) = x$. Does that make sense?

Edit 3: I just saw that this is exactly what you wrote in a comment to the question. I think it is perfectly fine.

Comment: The problem defines m and n only as m>=0, n>=0.  I'm pretty sure, after reviewing the problem, that the values of m and n are nonnegative integers.

Comment: Yeah, that seems pretty spot on.  I think my original problem was trying to actually construct the specific mapping instead of just intuitively using ordering principles and the fact that both sets contain elements that are positive integers.  My only concern was if it is actually true that each 2^m*3^n is unique for every m,n, but if you do what you did and define the set S recursively as a mapping of T onto S instead of finding the exact map from S to T, it seems much better.